# Convert a 1-5 digit number to alphanumeric 5 digit number

Tags: php, algorithm

I am looking for a way to convert a 1-5 digit int to a 5 digit alphanumeric number incrementally.

Example

```
for($i=0; $i<41; $i++){
    echo convert_i_to_alphanumeric($i);
}
```

OUTPUT//

00001
00002
00003
00004
00005
00006
00007
00008
00009
0000A
0000B
0000C
0000D
0000E
0000F
0000G
0000H
0000I
0000J
0000K
0000L
0000M
0000N
0000O
0000P
0000Q
0000R
0000S
0000T
0000U
0000V
0000W
0000X
0000Y
0000Z
00010
00011
00012
00013
00014
...

Comment: convert what? there seems to be no input

Comment: @Dagon $i as it increments, I see the confusion, I changed the question

Comment: Looks like you need [base-36](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_36).

Comment: ah ok, different definition of convert to me, this is pure creation :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Php has a [base_convert](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php) function you can use.

`base_convert($i,10,36)`

To get in the padded format you had, just add a [strtoupper](https://www.google.com/url?q=http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php&sa=U&ei=_gOMUYmvNsL0yQGzvoCADQ&ved=0CAcQFjAA&client=internal-uds-cse&usg=AFQjCNF_jQ3xbwQVBrAOY_56w-eUZ8tqmg) and [strpad](https://www.google.com/url?q=http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php&sa=U&ei=EQSMUfGOLqSuyQHStYDYCQ&ved=0CAcQFjAA&client=internal-uds-cse&usg=AFQjCNHPT_Jyu2BvN-dfXj2-3kLLXkVvKQ)

```
function convert_i_to_alphanumeric($digit) {
    return str_pad(strtoupper(base_convert($digit,10,36)),5,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```